# question with jquery validation

Tags: jquery, validation

I am trying to attach the validation on a button click. I have:

```
  <script>
 $().ready(function() {
//
    $("#btnAdd").click(function() { 

        $("#myForm").validate({                     
        // $("#crap").rules("add", {required: true,  messages: {required:"Required input"} });
        rules: { crap: "required" },
        messages: { crap: "required field"}
        // $("#myForm").validate();
        });   

});

}); 
</script>

<form method="post" id="myForm" name="myForm">
<input type="text" name="crap" id="crap" class="required" />
<br />
<input type="button" name="btnAdd" id="btnAdd" value="add" />
</form>
```

now, if i change btnAdd to a submit type, it works. otherwise, it won't. how can i call the validation on a button click ? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

validation happens on submit that is why it work..

do you not want to submit the form ?

you could invoke the submit function yourself
 by chaining the submit call to the validate one ..

```
$("#myForm").validate({                     
        // $("#crap").rules("add", {required: true,  messages: {required:"Required input"} });
        rules: { crap: "required" },
        messages: { crap: "required field"}
        // $("#myForm").validate();
        }).form();
```

**[EDIT]** Actually the validate plugin has the *form* method which triggers the validation, so chain that instead of the submit.. (updated in code above)

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/form

Comment: Nice one, weird though that it's called `.form()` on the validator, and `.valid()` on the form/elements

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#btnAdd').click(function (){
    if($("#formname").valid())
        alert("yes");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `validate()` call sets up validation on the form. It validates when the form is submitted. You can call `valid()` to force validation. See [docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation#Validate_forms_like_you.27ve_never_been_validating_before.21) and [demo](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/valid)

```
$().ready(function() {
    $("#myForm").validate({                     
        // $("#crap").rules("add", {required: true,  messages: {required:"Required input"} });
        rules: { crap: "required" },
        messages: { crap: "required field"}

    });   
    $("#btnAdd").click(function() {
        if($("#myForm").valid()) { 
            // Submit the form?
        }
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The validate is actually being attached to the form NOT the button. You do not have to put the

```
   $("#myForm").validate({...});
```

inside the button click code. The validation gets called on the form submit. A button does not automatically submit a form, but

```
<input type="submit".../>
```

does. That is why the form validation only kicks in when you use a submit input.

If you do need a button for some reason then you should have your button submit the form programmatically.